# Obtain the text-editor indent-size configuration for a Language in a VSIX-package

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

For my VSIX package, I can define configuration parameters for a language using the ProvideLanguageEditorOptionPage attribute. How to access them is also described.
But how can I access the predefined settings like tab size or indent size for the language? I can't find the description for this.

[image]